# How would you execute code only if you get a response from an async function?

Tags: flutter

I am currently using an async function to do a POST. Upon success you will get a User object, upon success I want to navigate to another page. Code will follow. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Code that performs the request

```
Future<User> loginUser(String username, String password) async{
  final http.Response response = await http.post(
    'https://bigboyauth.com/login',
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    },
    body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
      'username': username,
      'password': password
    }),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 201) {
    return User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to login user');
  }
}
```

Code that calls the POST then should navigate to another page upon a successful POST

```
          onTap: () {
            loginUser(passwordController.text, nameController.text);
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard())
            );
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods to achieve this.

1. Use await

```
onTap: () async {
   
   bool success = true;
  
  try {
    await loginUser(passwordController.text, nameController.text);
  } on Exception {
    success = false;
  }
  
  if(success) {
    Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard())
            );
  }
}
```

2. Use then

```
onTap: () {
    loginUser(passwordController.text, nameController.text).then((user){
        Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard())
            );
    }).catchError((error) => handleError(error));
}
```

To get more about Future, async, await: https://youtu.be/SmTCmDMi4BY

Answer (score 0):

Call `then` on your `Future<User>`. You can view the documentation [here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-async/Future/then.html).

You can call

```
loginUser(passwordController.text, nameController.text).then((v) {
  // This code will be called after the future completes
});
```

Additionally, I would recommend looking at the [dartz](https://pub.dev/packages/dartz) package to avoid throwing an exception inside your `loginUser` method.

Answer (score 0):

why not navigate after checking the HTTP statusCode

```
    Future<User> loginUser(String username, String password) async{
      final http.Response response = await http.post(
        'https://bigboyauth.com/login',
        headers: <String, String>{
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        body: jsonEncode(<String, String>{
          'username': username,
          'password': password
        }),
      );
      if (response.statusCode == 201) {
         User.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
         Navigator.push(context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Dashboard(),
         )
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to login user');
      }
    }
```